# Does a word deceived in Genesis 3:13 mean that the serpent lied to Eve? Some translations say,"the serpent caused me to forget"

Tags: genesis, serpent, eve

I'm doing the study and I just had the question because we're talking about God's calling for remembrance by his people. God's constantly telling us to remember the things he's done because we tend as humans to forget the wonderful works and then we lack in faith during our walk on earth. in Genesis 3:13, one translation says the serpent caused me to forget. So I want to make sure I accurately represent that verse and that the shortcoming of Eve was that she forgot God's teaching. If that is the case, I'd like to be able to use that verse when I teach how important it is to remember God's teachings and his miracles

> And Jehovah God saith to the woman, 'What is this thou hast done?' and the woman saith, `The serpent hath **caused me to forget** -- and I do eat.' [Young's Literal Translation](https://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/1003013)

Comment: The serpent certainly misrepresented a number of things to Eve, one of them being that the tree of knowledge was not 'in the midst'. Another being that God never said not to 'touch' it, only not to 'eat' it. And most importantly he misrepresented the righteousness of God as if that righteousness were a matter of God keeping law. (In which case he is suggesting that law is above Deity, which  breaks the commandment 'ye shall have no other gods before me'.) Up-voted +1. Edited just to add the reference. Welcome to SE-BH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Genesis 3:13 Does the Hebrew actually say הִשִּׁיאַ֖נִי deceived ME?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/4959/genesis-313-does-the-hebrew-actually-say-%d7%94%d6%b4%d7%a9%d6%b4%d6%bc%d7%81%d7%99%d7%90%d6%b7%d6%96%d7%a0%d6%b4%d7%99-deceived-me)

Comment: Don't rely on Young Literal or any such version

Answer (score 2):

The operative word in Gen 3:13 is נָשָׁא (nasha) whose BDB entry is given in the appendix below.

The word occurs 15 times on the OT and is always translated "beguile", deceive, or similar.  Gen 3:13, 2 Kings 18:29, 19:10, 2 Chron 32:15, Isa 19:13, 36:14, 37:10, Jer 4:10, 23:39, 29:8, 37:9, 49:16, Obad 1:3, 7.

Indeed, another well-used Lexicon is W Baker and E Carpenter's "Complete Word Study Dictionary OT" which has this entry for the same word:

> A verb meaning to deceive.  It meanas to use deceptive methods or
> deceit to accomplish something; to deceive a person (Gen 3:13); to
> deceive people by political means giving false hopes of deliverance (2
> Kings 18:29, 19:10, 2 Chr 32:15); death deceives persons surprising
> them (Ps 55:15); it describes the prophecies of false prophets (Jer
> 29:8).  It refers to those who deceive themselves (Jer 37:9, 49:16,
> Obad 1:3, 7); or are deceived (Isa 19:13).  It describes God's
> deceiving His people, of His making false assertions of peace (Jer
> 4:10).

In short, I am at a loss to understand the YLT and ISV versions of Gen 3:13, "caused me to forget".  The several dozen other versions I consulted (see https://biblehub.com/parallel/genesis/3-13.htm ) all have deceived, tricked, beguiled, or similar.

**APPENDIX - BDB entry for נָשָׁא (nasha)**

> נָשָׁא verb only Niph`al, Hiph`il **beguile**, deceive; — (kindred with I.
> שׁוא, from which, however, the forms can hardly be derived
> (conjectures We compare 2. 351)); —
>
> Niph`al Perfect3plural נִשְּׁאוּ Isaiah 19:13 the princes have been
> **beguiled** ("" נוֺאֲלוּ, הִתְעוּ).
>
> Hiph`il Perfect הִשִּׁיא Jeremiah 49:16, suffix הִשִּׁאַ֫נִי Genesis
> 3:13, הִשִּׁיאֶ֑ךָ Obadiah 3; 2masculine singular הִשֵּׁאתָ Jeremiah
> 4:10; 3plural suffix הִשִּׁיא֫וּךָ Obadiah 7; Imperfect only jussive
> יַשִּׁיא2Chronicles 32:15, so Psalm 55:16 Qr (see below); יַשִּׁא 2
> Kings 18:29; Isaiah 36:14, suffix יַשִּׁאֲךָ 2 Kings 19:10; Isaiah
> 37:10; 2masculine plural תַּשִּׁאוּ Jeremiah 37:9; Infinitive absolute
> הַשֵּׁא Jeremiah 4:10; — **beguile**, usually with accusative of person
> Genesis 3:13 (J; not elsewhere Hexateuch); Jeremiah 49:16; Obad 3:7;
> אַליַֿשִּׁאֲךָ 2 Kings 19:10 let not thy God **beguile** thee = Isaiah
> 37:10, of Hezekiah 2 Chronicles 32:15 (compare below), אַלתַּֿשִּׁאוּ
> נַפְשֹׁתֵיכֶם Jeremiah 37:9 do not **deceive** yourselves; also followed
> by ל person אַליַֿשִּׁא לָכֶם 2 Kings 18:29 = Isaiah 36:14 (= 2
> Chronicles 32:15, see above), Jeremiah 29:8; הַזֶּה הַשֵּׁא הִשֵּׁאתָ
> לָעָם Jeremiah 4:10 thou hast utterly **beguiled** this people; ישׁימות
> עָלֵימוֺ Psalm 55:16 Kt apparently = desolations (be) upon them! (but
> elsewhere only in proper name, of a location, compare p. 445 above), <
> Qr יַשִּׁיא מָוֶת עלימו Ew Ol Pe De NowHup, compare ᵐ5, let death
> (beguile them, i.e.) come deceitfully upon them! Brüll Che, compare
> Bae, conjectures plausibly יַשִּׁיא מָוֶת יִבְלָעֵמוֺ.

Comment: I think that the "caused me to forget" rendering leaves out that in the event, Eve's "forgetting" was deliberate; she pushed her knowledge of God's law out of her thinking. *Beguile* is not a terribly common word in regular English usage, and perhaps those translators wanted something that required less explanation; but still they missed the mark.

Answer (score 0):

"The serpent caused me to forget---and I ate."

I agree with the comments above about what Satan caused the woman to forget. But the underlying, fundamental thing stolen from Eve in forgetting was her identity. Man was created in the image of God. We are the "very good" of His creation--His masterpieces. Eve "forgot" who she was and how God had created her to live. YLT can be understood best as "The serpent caused me to forget **who I was** and I ate."

Comment: Welcome to the site, Mary. If you take the Tour (below) you will see what is required for Qs and As here. The verse in question needs to be examined to find proof in it for... whatever your answer claims. Do you have any textual basis for saying the YLT includes 'who I was' in it? That may be based on interpretation of some Bible points, but this site is not looking for that, or for peoples' opinions. It would be good if you could expand your answer on the basis of what the Hebrew text actually says.